Convention based OpenApi schema generation for dotnet and NSwag
So I am getting tired from adding the same [ProducesResponseType] attribute on my WebAPI controller methods over and over, and I thought there must be an easier, convention based way. I mean, the method clearly tells the return type:
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType<UserSummary[]>(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public Task<UserSummary[]> GetAllUsers()
{
    return ExecuteAsync(new AllUserSummariesQuery());
}

I started to dig a little bit into NSwag and found it could be easily achieved by writing an operation processor:
public class OpenApiResponseTypeConvention : IOperationProcessor
{
    public bool Process(OperationProcessorContext context)
    {
        var method = context.MethodInfo;
        var returnType = method.ReturnType;

        if (returnType.IsGenericType && returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>))
        {
            returnType = returnType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }

        if (!returnType.IsGenericType && returnType == typeof(Task))
        {
            returnType = typeof(void);
        }

        if (returnType == typeof(void))
        {
            context.OperationDescription.Operation.Responses["204"] = new OpenApiResponse();
        }
        else
        {
            var responseDescription = new OperationResponseDescription("200", returnType, false, string.Empty);
            var schema = context.SchemaGenerator.Generate(returnType, context.SchemaResolver);

            context.OperationDescription.Operation.Responses[responseDescription.StatusCode] = new OpenApiResponse
            {
                Content = { ["application/json"] = new OpenApiMediaType { Schema = schema } },
            };
        }

        return true;
    }
}

The convention is

return HTTP 204 NoContent when the return type is void (or just a Task)
return HTTP 200 Ok when the return type is a specific type (or a Task of a specific type) and derive the schema from the CLR's response type

Now I am wondering why this isn't the default and if I am overlooking a problem. I am aware of the more "opinionated" approach, but at least in this type of project I am totally fine with it.

Now I am wondering why this isn't the default, it's for clarity. specially if the project has more contributors than yourself. using Attribute would be faster to follow than a behavioral class that works somewhere else. It would be nice if they just add some attributes to extend the IOperationProcessor, so it would be more customizable and visible to the human eye.

Overall very nice. Concise, easy to follow, quite clear when the description is available. A few suggestions anyways:
Documentation
I hope you have at least a bit of documentation on that code in the form of xmldocs to aid future readers of this code in understanding what you're trying to do (and possibly why it's a good idea).
If you don't: now is the time to add it, while it's still clear in your memory.
Bailing out
As it is, this code will always run, even for operations that don't follow the convention. There should be a nice clear way for these sorts of endpoints to not be affected by the operation processor.
Maybe something like the following aircode would be appropriate for when you explicitly want to specify the response type:
var method = context.MethodInfo;
var explicitResponseSpec = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ProducesResponseTypeAttribute), true);

if (explicitResponseSpec.Any(spec => IsSuccessStatus(spec.StatusCode))
{
    // Bail on response specification by convention, since we have explicit specification
    return true;
}

